# length=0; index=5

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I need to know what is the problem with this code??

```
public String getLastDate(){
    SQLiteDatabase database = lecturesDB.getReadableDatabase();
    try {
        String [] a = {DATE};
        Cursor cursor = database.query(LECTURES_TABLE, a, null, null, null, null, null);
        int i = cursor.getColumnIndex(DATE);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        String ld = cursor.getString(i);//Thu, 26 Mar 2015 17:19:56
        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss ");
        Date date = format.parse(ld.substring(5));

        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            String c = cursor.getString(i);
            if (format.parse(c.substring(5)).getTime()>date.getTime()){
                date = format.parse(c.substring(5));
                ld = c;
            }
        }
        return ld;
    }catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Mayiaz",e.getMessage());return "";
    }finally {
        database.close();
    }
}
```

Its return `""` and the exception show this message :

```
"04-04 19:55:45.702    1478-1634/com.mine.rbt E/Mayiaz﹕ length=0; index=5"
```

Why is the code throwing an exception, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? What kind of `Exception` did you catch? Where did it come from?

Comment: thank you for replay but the problem was solved :) @GáborBakos :*

Comment: can you shed some light on what was the problem and the solution or was it too trivial enough to maybe consider deleting the question? :D

Comment: it was in the ld.substring(5) and c.substring(5) statment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I'm assuming that this occurs on the `ld.substring(5)` line; if it is on the `c.substring(5)` line, replace `s/ld/c/g`. Please indicate clearly which line the exception occurs on)

You can't invoke `String.substring(i)` for `i` greater than the string's length. You need to avoid invoking `ld.substring(5)` if `ld` is shorter than 5 characters (in this case, it is empty).

For example, you could use `Math.min(5, ld.length())`. Note, however, that this will probably cause an exception to be thrown because the string can't be parsed as a date by `format`.